# Creating a table from existing data file, only last row value remains

Tags: python

I'm just starting with python and I have a basic question about creating tables.

I have a file called example.txt as follow:

```
# Header information 1
# Header information 2
# Header information 3
# Header information 4
# var1  var2      var3      var4      var5
# Header information 5
# Header information 6
    1   6500.0    5.052300  1.020020  9.355021
    2   2500.7    3.038809  0.033637  1.736393
    3    750.6    5.003003  0.047254  3.287092
...
...
...
  100   2700.6    9.002800  0.088105  8.289851
```

I want to create a table using the name of the variables (var1, var2, etc.) as header names. I have tried this:

```
fnExample = open('example.txt', 'r')
i = 0
for line in fnExample:
    i = i + 1
    if i==5 :
        varExample = [word.strip() for word in line.split()]
    if (i>7 and i<100):
        dataExample = [word.strip() for word in line.split()]
        datatable[varExample[1]]=dataExample[0]
        datatable[varExample[2]]=dataExample[1]
        datatable[varExample[3]]=dataExample[2]
        datatable[varExample[4]]=dataExample[3]
        datatable[varExample[5]]=dataExample[4]

print(datatable['var1']) # gives only the last value of var1
```

Why does my `datatable` only contain the last value, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You overwrite the values at each key of `datatable` in every iteration, it is not surprising that what remains after the last iteration is the values from the last iteration.

Comment: You probably want `datatable` to be a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, please take the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). I edited your title to summarize the question and remove the unnecessary tag (since tags have their own section). I also modified your vague ending into the specific question you seemed to be asking, but please change that if you have a different question. It would be good if you [edit] your question to include what output you actually want from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the values at each key of `datatable` in every iteration, it is not surprising that what remains after the last iteration is the values from the last iteration. You should create a list to hold the dictionaries for *all rows* before you start iterating, then create a new dictionary for each row and append it to the list in every iteration.

I used a loop / dict comprehension to do this instead of writing five lines. Also I'm not sure why you associated the `1`th column name from the header to the `0`th column, but I've left that behavior intact in case it's correct. If you want to change it and associate the `0`th header to the `0`th column, remove the `varExample = varExample[1:]` line.

```
fnExample = open('example.txt', 'r')

datatable = []

for i, line in enumerate(fnExample):
    if i == 5 :
        varExample = [word.strip() for word in line.split()]
        varExample = varExample[1:] # Discard the first element of the vars because you don't use it
    elif i > 7 and i < 100:
        dataExample = [word.strip() for word in line.split()]
        row_dict = {var: data for var, data in zip(varExample, dataExample)}
        datatable.append(row_dict)

fnExample.close()

print(datatable) # prints the entire list
```

If you're using pandas, you can now create a full dataframe using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(datatable)
```

<sup>Mind you, if you're using pandas anyway, you can specify a list of rows to skip as the `skiprows` argument to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and you'll have the same result in a single function call</sup>

I am not familiar with the [datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package if you're using that, but I'm sure there's a way to convert your list of dicts into one if you look through the docs.

---

If you want your data to be structured as a *dictionary* instead, where each key gives you a list of data in that column, that is easy too. In this case, create a dict when you read the column names, and set the values of those keys to empty lists. Then append to these lists when you read the rows.

```
for i, line in enumerate(fnExample):
    if i == 5 :
        varExample = [word.strip() for word in line.split()]

        datatable = {var: [] for var in varExample[1:]} # Ignore the first element of the vars because you don't use it
        
    elif i > 7 and i < 100:
        dataExample = [word.strip() for word in line.split()]
        for lst, data in zip(datatable.values(), dataExample):
            lst.append(data)
```

Now, `print(datatable['var1'])` will print all the values in the column `var1`.

Comment: Thanks Pranav for this answer. It helps a lot. I test your 2 solutions, but both let the data as str type.
I had to add the following lines to change to the values to float type
`code`
    for i, line in enumerate(df):   
        df['var1'][i]=float(df['var1'][i])
        df['var2'][i]=float(df['var2'][i])
`code`
Do you know if there is a way to do the same for an unknown number of variables?

Comment: @Aalcon you could just convert them to floats while you are parsing the file in the first place? `row_dict = {var: float(data) for var, data in zip(varExample, dataExample)}` for the first case, and `lst.append(float(data))` for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the the whole table, you can use pandas method `pandas.read_csv` and ignore the lines you don't need:

```
import pandas
datatable = pandas.read_csv('example.txt', sep=r'\s+',skiprows=[0,1,2,3,5,6])
```

Just have in mind that the separator `sep=' '` must spaces for every column, `'\s+'` allows being one or more space. Also, you don't have to use the parameter `head=4` because the other rows are ignored and the 4th row becomes the 1st row (header by default)

Example file:

```
Header information 1
Header information 2
Header information 3
Header information 4
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
Header information 5
Header information 6
1 6500.0 5.052300 1.020020 9.355021
2 2500.7 3.038809 0.033637 1.736393
3 750.6 5.003003 0.047254 3.287092
```

Output:

```
var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
0   1   6500.0  5.052300    1.020020    9.355021
1   2   2500.7  3.038809    0.033637    1.736393
2   3   750.6   5.003003    0.047254    3.287092
```

Comment: `sep=r"\s+"` will treat multiple whitespace as a single separator